# IBM Sterling order management - Email Server

Tags: email, smtp, mail-server, ibm-sterling

I'm trying to send the mail to the store (Node), on the onsucess event of createOrder api.

So for this, I've created 2 new services.

The first service receives the information from the onsucess event of the createOrder api and passes it on to the queue.

The second service receives the information from that queue and passes it on to the email server.

This sends the email. The problem is that for some of the orders the email is not sending, but we are not getting any exceptions for these.

In the logs for those orders it shows the "Successful Acknowledgement from the email server".

I don't know where the exact problem is. I have checked the email server, but cannot find anything related to the missing order information.

What steps can I take to further debug this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are saying, only some orders have this problem . Then it will be something related with the order details like the email id associated with it. And also if the successful message in logs shows message has been sent. But if it is a customized log please check it once again. If its Ok then please check the Email Server logs directly.

Comment: But when I try to resend the mail, by posting the input message directly to the service through API tester, it is reaching successfully. So I hope, there won't be any problem with the email id. Also we have around 20 stores and each store have different email Ids. The problem here is the emails missing are not related to the specific store's email Id, it is happening for almost all the stores, but for example 1 out of 10 mails are missing.

Comment: 1 out 10 is missing for all stores! So can you just debug if its always missing from the last or from a particular index. I think in configurator we are not setting up these things in any complex way... So probably any user defined class will be using for this mail sending.